# API key not found

Tags: react-native, api-key

I'm trying out React Native Maps but get this when I do `react-native run-android`:

```
API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

My `meta-data` tag from **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.maptest"
android:value="A***Q"
/>
```

I have tried restarting the packager.

Solution: `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` is literal and shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file add the following :-

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="Your Google maps API Key Here"/>
```

and then run react-native run-android again and you are good to go :)

**edit**

You can't change the literal "API_KEY" in android:name, Set the android:name as `"com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"`

Comment: I don't understand. I don't see the difference between the code you pasted and mine.

Could you point out what I did incorrectly, please?

Comment: Replace android:name="com.google.android.geo.maptest" to ==>> 
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY". let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: I didn't know the API_KEY was literal. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it is a literal so you can't replace it and i hope it is working perfect now :)

Comment: Done. Thank you for adding the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

> In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the  element, by inserting it just before the closing  tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

[please click here for reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Answer (score 3):

In  AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the application:
AppName\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="Your API Key Will be inserted here"/>
  <activity......
```

Then rebuild the app and this will solve the problem.
[Snapshot of AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om36a.png)